# why dbt runs in cli but throws an error on cloud UI for the exact same model?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, dbt

I am executing `dbt run -s model_name` on CLI and the task completes successfully. However, when I run the exact same command on dbt cloud, I get this error:

```
Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. 
  Error message from server: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: 
  Error running query: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot 
      resolve '`pv.meta.uuid`' given input columns: []; line 6 pos 4;
      \n'Project ['pv.meta.uuid AS page_view_uuid#249595,
      'pv.user.visitorCookieId AS (80) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

it looks like it fails recognizing '`pv.meta.uuid`' syntax which extract data from a json format. It is not clear to me what is going on. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Most likely your CLI and Cloud are operating on different targets (so, different underlying data). Have you confirmed that the table upstream from this one is identical for the CLI run and the Cloud run?

Comment: Awesome, thank you! the issue was different targets actually. do you mind explaining your thought process please? the error message does not entirely address the issue directly I thought

Comment: The `... given input columns: []` seemed like a hint to me